# gcc linker not linking programs under debian 7.4 wheezy 32-bit, gnome 3.4.2

Tags: c, linux, gcc, debian

My system is 64 bit but i installed debian 7.4 wheezy with Gnome 3.4.2
when I run gcc, i get the following error from linker

```
>gcc -o first first.c

/usr/bin/ld:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o:1: syntax error
```

I tried reinstalling gcc, glibc and binutils.
My system is actually 64 bit, but I had 32 bit debian image, could that be the issue ?

I am not cross compiling and first.c is a hello world application.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{

printf("hello world");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you install a 64- or 32-bit GCC? How about the `binutils` package (which contains the `ld` linker program)?

Comment: gcc came pre-installed and since the image is 32 bit, the gcc would be 32 bit. here's version on commandline                                             guest@debian:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2

Comment: What do `file /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o` or `readelf -h /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o` report?

Comment: root@debian:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7# file /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o
**/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o: data**
root@debian:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7# readelf -h crtbegin.o
**readelf: Error: Not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start**

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled the following packages:
cpp-4.7 (4.7.2-5)
gcc-4.7 (4.7.2-5)
gcc-4.7-base (4.7.2-5)

Thanks to @David Collins, I realized that the crtbegin.o file and the other one were kind of not ok. So I reinstalled gcc packages above. I had gcc base, gcc 4.6 and 4.7, i only reinstalled the latest ones which resolved the issue. Thank you David Collins.